# jQuery Correct Syntax in simple Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't  understand why `data: 'txt=' + $('#nombre').value,` doesn't work but `data: 'txt=' + document.formulario.nombre.value,` works.

Here is the js code:

```
function validarNombre(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://redwow.net/jqueryajax.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'txt=' + $('#nombre').value,
        success: function(datos){
                alert(datos);
        },
    });
};
```

And here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejemplo Ajax Personalizado</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryajax.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="formulario">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre:</td><td><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" onKeyPress="validarNombre()"/></td>
            </tr><tr style="visibility:hidden;">
                <td>E-mail:</td><td><input type="text" id="email"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `data: 'txt=' + $('#nombre').val()` and not `data: 'txt=' + $('#nombre').value`

Comment: If you want to use value you should use document.getElementById("nombre").value. If you are using JQuery the val()  will give you the value of the element.

Comment: Thank you, only one more question, what about of doing something like this? `$('#nombre').style.visibility = 'hidden';` on success function.

Comment: Instead of that use css method of JQuery, $('#nombre').css("visibility", "hidden")

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
  var sm = $('#nombre').val();
function validarNombre(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://redwow.net/jqueryajax.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'txt=' + sm ,
        success: function(datos){
                alert(datos);
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the benefit of declare the variable outside the function?